# Bolt CMS Static html page gets 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, bolt-cms, static-pages

recently i have started to use Bolt CMS. i have made a theme with Angular JS but i wanted to use some static pages. as they mentioned in their Doc `https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/templates/templates-routes#automatic-template-selection` i have added my link to `routing.yml`

**Example:**

```
oldpages:
  path:           /applications/forms/chakka/ng/templates/core.html
  defaults:       { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record', 'contenttypeslug': 'page' }
  requirements:
    slug:       '[a-z0-9-_]+'
```

but i get an

> Exception --> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   HttpException

Page page/ not found.

I am really new to bolt CMS. anyone knows why ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the template binding:

```
templatebinding:
    path: /mytemplate
    defaults: { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::template', template: 'mytemplate' }
```